# Filter to a specific timeframe in AWS logs while keeping the log context

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there a way to jump to a specific time within the AWS CloudWatch logs, instead of endlessly scrolling through 20 or 30 lines at a time?

I can filter to the last X hours/minutes/etc. but this isn't granular enough. I can also filter for a specific log line using the search feature. But after filtering to a specific log line, I want to see lines around that log line (the context). If I try to remove the filter, then it takes me back to the default filter, which means I lose my place in the logs and I have to go back to scrolling through lots of log lines again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of tools that you can use to better visualize what you are looking for. One such tool I use is,

https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs

Lot of Commercial tools are also available,

https://www.loggly.com/product/aws-log-analysis/

https://www.splunk.com/blog/2017/02/03/how-to-easily-stream-aws-cloudwatch-logs-to-splunk.html

There are tons in that category,

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/b/4988009011?ref_=nav_category_4988009011

Hope it helps.